# Unable to read kakfa messages through spark streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We are writing the spark streaming application, to read kafka messages using createStream method and batch interval is 180 seconds.

The code successfully working and creating files for every 180 seconds into s3 buckets , but no messages in the files. Below is the Environment

Spark 2.3.0
Kakfa 1.0

Please go through code and please let me know anything wrong here

---

```
#import dependencies
import findspark

findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkContext

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

import json

from pyspark.sql import *
```

## Creating Context variables

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="SparkStreamingwithPython").getOrCreate()

sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc,180)

topic="thirdtopic"

ZkQuorum = "localhost:2181"
```

## Connect to Kafka And create Stream

```
kakfaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,ZkQuorum,"Spark-Streaming-Consumer",{topic:1})

def WritetoS3(rdd):
     rdd.saveAsTextFile("s3://BucketName/thirdtopic/SparkOut")

kakfaStream.foreachRDD(WritetoS3)
ssc.start()

ssc.awaitTermination()
```

---

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using Kafka Connect for S3?

Comment: Thanks for reply ,but we are not depending on confluent, we are using apche Kafka and spark only or you are suggesting to create own connector.

Comment: Kafka Connect is an open source framework. Confluent only maintains the code. Anyone that can run Maven should be able to compile that S3 connect code, and add it onto plain Kafka servers